# What is the meaning and usage of ネタ?

Tags: usage, translation

For example in this phrase:

> 話すネタはもっていそう

I translate it into "he might have some stories", but I have the impression it has many other meanings.

Comment: For basic translation and examples use a dictionary: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1Q%A4%CD%A4%BF_1_ and click on the small [Ex] link for the first result.

Comment: I understand that the contents of the question seems a bit basic, but I was expecting a bit more discussion regarding this word. There are a couple of good answers already pretty much what I was hoping for.

Comment: Check out the definitions and examples on [this page](http://www.jekai.org/entries/aa/00/nn/aa00nn60.htm), too. (<3 jeKai)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ネタ is a semi-slang term that comes from reversing the characters of "seed" タネ. It's a word with many uses, but in all uses it denotes the "seed" of the idea of a work, it's essential core.

In cooking, the ネタ of a dish is the key ingredient that makes a particular dish interesting. For example, the ネタ of a piece of sushi is the non-rice part of the sushi.

In a magic trick, the ネタ of a trick is the actual trickery that makes the illusion work (the part that Penn and Teller reveal).

In a joke, the ネタ is the core subject and punchline, before you pad them out with a story.

In news articles, the ネタ is the raw fact being reported (e.g. "oil rig explodes") before being fleshed out with prose.

In your example of 「話すネタ」, ネタ means topic of conversation.

Comment: +1 for the elaborate examples :)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate list of explanations. I found that Wikipedia has good explanations supporting your answer:
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8D%E3%82%BF


Furthermore, it seems that ネタバレ can be translated as spoiler,
literally "revealing the core subject":
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8D%E3%82%BF%E3%83%90%E3%83%AC

Comment: @SuperElectric, @Axioplase In case of magic tricks, it's rather used without reversing as `種` (tane) or `種明かし` (taneakasi) 'revealing the trick'.

Comment: @sawa I would say that both ネタ and 種 are used for magic. ネタ: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/170158/m0u/ネタ/ With 種, we get the standard magician's "disclaimer": 種も仕掛けもございません.

Answer (score 5):

ネタ alone is a bit vague: "stories", but usually in the sense of jokes or funny anecdotes. I'd say it has some connotation of "dirty" (or at least slightly off-colour) jokes/anecdotes, but that's more a matter of usage than intrinsic meaning.

ネタ is most often encountered in these two expressions:

- 下ネタ【しもねた】(or 下のネタ): lit. "jokes about down below", i.e. "dirty jokes"
- ネタばれ: "spoilers"...

You can probably encounter it in other expressions, where it carries the meaning of "joke". E.g.:

> いい加減パンツネタはやめとけよな → Quit with the panty jokes!

In your example, I would translate it by "He seems to have some funny stories" or "good stories" etc.

Comment: ネタ can also be a magic trick.